# MVC 4 edit route parameter in controller

Tags: c#, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm having a little problem i hope someone can help me with.

on ASP.net MVC 4 (C#) i need to be able to edit the parameters of my route from my controller.

example the request url is

```
MyController/MyAction/param1/param2
```

now from `MyAction` I need to edit the returned url so that it displays

```
MyController/MyAction/Modifiedparam1/Modifiedparam2
```

The purpose of this is to translate the parameters that i retrieve from my database from language changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use redirect result for this (in `MyAction` on some condition):

```
return RedirectToAction("MyAction", { param1Name = Modifiedparam1, param2Name = Modifiedparam2 };
```

Basically you cannot modify url in controller. Urls is something send by the browser to invoke some action. You may just say browser to redirect user to another url.

Comment: This is what im currently doing but using this technique i need to reload the data from my DB a second time.

Comment: Do you have any issues with performance? How often is this operation? You may use cache. Also, if users come into this situation after clicking on your web site links than probably you need to update links to have modified params instead of current (if it's ok).

Comment: In a way if you consider that it only does this when you change languages of the site i guess double reload wont happen too often. All the links to these pages are dynamically loaded according to the page set language. ill say this confirmed what i had already done. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Don't fight with framework. It will fight back sooner or later. Instead follow mvc principles, redirect from controller action or filters/interceptors to do so.